# findall Python change syntax of re.findall Word a10n

Tags: python, task, findall

Im stuck in my re findall syntax

`new_s = re.findall(r"[A-Za-z@#0-9]+|\W+", s)`

But I am not familiar with this re syntax, right now I make 50% of "Word a10n (abbreviation)" kata.

is it possible to change re.findall sitntax to complete this kata?

```
import re
def abbreviate(s):
    
    new_s = re.findall(r"[A-Za-z@#0-9]+|\W+", s)
    n = []
    for i in new_s:    
        if len(i)>3 and i.isalpha():
            l = len(i)-2
            n.append(f"{i[0]}{l}{i[-1]}")
        else:
            n.append(i)
    
    return "".join(n)
```

source https://www.codewars.com/kata/5375f921003bf62192000746/train/python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got some points missing, but nice usage of `findall`, I like it and great job :)

---

1. You separated each "part" by piping `|` in the regex pattern, but you should pipe the numbers as well!
2. You need to separate the "special separators/characters" as well! i.e. the `@#_` characters.

So your regex pattern should be:

```
r"[A-Za-z]+|\W+|[0-9]|[@#_]"
```